# VB6 On Error GoTo Line x or Exit Do

Tags: error-handling, vb6, goto

I've got a `Do Until` loop in my code which in some circumstances may error. However due to the error, I only want the code to exit the `Do Until` loop and continue with the rest of the subroutine.

I've tried using `On Error Exit Do` but this says

> Expected GoTo or Resume

Then I tried using `On Error GoTo 5865`, as 5865 is the line after the loop that it needs to continue executing from, however, this says

> Label not defined

How am I able to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare an error trapper at the top of your SUB or FUNCTION, i.e.:

```
On Error Goto ErrTrap
```

In this case, "ErrTrap" is a label, and it would typically be at the bottom of your routine:

```
ErrTrap:

If Err.Number = ... Then
   ...
   Resume AfterError ' another label
End If

MsgBox("Error blah blah")
```

Above "ErrTrap:" you would place an

`Exit Sub` or `Exit Function` accordingly

and you would place "AfterError:" wherever you want the code to resume after a handled error.

This is a simplification of a much more complex subject - there are a lot of options to error handling, including line number trapping, Resume Next, etc., but this should be enough to get you what you want for now.  Research the subject for more information.